# String_numput<> facet not writing to string

Tags: c++

I have written a String_numput<> facet that derives from the num_put<> facet, in order to write to a string.
The program is based on an example given by Stroustrup:

```
/// A num_put<> facet specialization that writes to a string
template<typename C>
class String_numput : public std::num_put<
                         C,
                         typename std::basic_string<C>::iterator>
{
public:
   String_numput() :
      /// this facet won't go into a locale;
      /// it has a manually controlled lifetime
      std::num_put<C, typename std::basic_string<C>::iterator> {1}
   {
   }
};
```

It is tested as follows:

```
using namespace std;

string s {};


void test(long i,
          string& s,
          int pos)
{
   String_numput<char> f;

   /// Format i into s at position pos;
   /// use cout's formatting rules
   f.put(s.begin() + pos, cout, ' ', i);

   cout << s;
}


int main()
{
   test(4567.9, s, 0);

   cout << "completed" << endl;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4e8386682471e7d

However, nothing is written to the string. The O/P is:

```
completed
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on an answer [elsewhere](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/227771/), I have designed the solution as follows:

1) [**String_numput**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb1dfbb4ebe7caa3) : will write a numeric to a string at a specified position. The string must be large enough to accommodate the numeric.

2) [**String_numapp**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1351d3a052c3022a) : will append a numeric to a string using a back_inserter.

The solution is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
f.put(s.begin() + pos, cout, ' ', i);
```

the first argument is supposed to be an output iterator, but you give it the `begin()` of an empty string.

This has two problems:

1. it is illegal: it will overwrite the end of the empty [begin,end) range of `s`, so you're probably trampling some random memory, and
2. and it doesn't expand the string, so `s.size()` stays zero, so `cout << s` will insert zero characters of your damaged range.

You need a `back_inserter` instead of a `string::iterator` - this will actually append to your string correctly.

**Note** that `std::num_put` has *two* template parameters, and the second is the type expected for the iterator argument to `put`.

You're explicitly setting it to `std::basic_string<C>::iterator`, but if you change the iterator you pass to `put`, you need to change this  second template parameter to match its type.

Comment: Conceptually, you are right - the string is empty. A string with sufficient blank space is accepted by f.put() and works. However, a back_inserter(s) isn't accepted by f.put(). [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea34d474bdc108d4). Error is `no matching function for call to 'String_numput<char>::put(std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::ostream&, char, long int&)'`